# trim a string of text, after a hyphen media in python

Tags: python, string

I just started with python, now I see myself needing the following, I have the following string:

```
1184-7380501-2023-183229
```

what i need is to trim this string and get only the following characters after the first hyphen. it should be as follows:

```
1184-738
```

how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
s = "1184-7380501-2023-183229"

print(s[:8])
```

Or perhaps

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'^\d+-...')
m = pattern.search(s)
print(m[0])
```

which accommodates variable length numeric prefixes.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* (you can do this a lot of different ways) use `partition()` and `join()`...

```py
"".join([token[:3] if idx == 2 else token for idx, token in enumerate("1184-7380501-2023-183229".partition("-"))])
```